# Getting Wrong Position in Fancy Cover Flow

Tags: android, android-layout, position, coverflow

I have a code with on item click listener on Fancy cover flow. But I am getting wrong position on click event. Please help me resolving it. 
I also tried using On Item Selected Listener. It didn't work.

activity.java

```
// spinner
        fancy.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int i, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Log.d("clicked_position",i);

                //Whenever I click, sometimes I get wrong Position, sometimes correct position.

            }

        });
```

Comment: Post whenever you getting eror.

Comment: plz add some code...

Comment: System.out.println?? you should use Log for better observation.

Comment: ya i have used a log too but to show just i have used sys out. hope you understand

Comment: maybe you did somethings wrong with your adapter.

Comment: What is the spacing value you set to your fancycoverflow?

Answer (score 0):

```
fancyCoverFlow
                        .setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
                                    View view, int position, long id) {

                                Log.e(getPackageName(), "position:- "
                                        + position);

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                            }
                        });
```

Comment: I think when you use it in Landscape mode this will not be True.